# LaTex Error: Environment table undefined

Tags: r, latex, knitr, stargazer

```
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-
mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: Thu, Feb 01, 2018 - 9:13:45 PM
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}
{Max} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
emoreg & 270 & 2.043 & 0.817 & 0.000 & 3.000 \\ 
treat & 270 & 0.604 & 0.490 & 0 & 1 \\ 
bullying & 270 & 0.755 & 0.559 & 0.000 & 2.571 \\ 
timetran & 270 & 8.281 & 7.233 & 0 & 90 \\ 
playsup & 270 & 4.459 & 0.619 & 1 & 5 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

I have downloaded MikTeX. I have installed and loaded "knitr". I saved the file as `.tex` and `.rnw`. I keep getting the following error: "LaTeX Error: Environment table undefined", along with others. I am able to make PDF documents with other environments such as `article`. Isn't `table` a base command, or do I need a package for the `table` environment? What is happening here?

[image: LaTex Errors]

Comment: Please read some introductory texts on LaTeX. The basic level is not an environment but the document class with „article“ being one of them. The above code is just a snippet that could be placed inside a full document.